# Sharepoint 2013 & Angular 2

Tags: sharepoint-server, angular2

Hello my fellow developers. 
As the title implies I have an issue when I try to integrate Angular 2 with SP 2013. 
Angular needs several files from node_modules in order to work. The problem is that I don't know how to include those files to my solution. Has anyone encountered something relevant? 
I have tried to create a new Layouts mapped folder and add the node_modules in there to reference them in the head of my page but I had no success since VS is crashing whenever I try to include node_modules in my solution.
Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: how is your visual studios project set up? Is it a template for a webpart? It is an empty project?

Comment: @Mike basically I'm creating a new sharepoint page and I'm trying to reference Angular there. I'm not sure if I answered your question

Comment: You are creating a new Page in VS? You mentioned VS, so wanted to get an idea what you are building.

Comment: @Mike I'm provisioning a page from VS to be exact. Sorry but I'm fairly new with SP as well as with its terminology.

Comment: This might help you out...https://askmanisha.wordpress.com/2016/08/10/create-basic-sharepoint-add-in-using-angular-2/

Comment: I managed to make this work but now I'm getting another error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastindexof' of undefined. The file that is throwing the exception is system.src.js